# "A little too many" or "A few too many"?

Tags: word-choice

I dont know whether to choose few or little in sentences like :
"I bought a little/ a few too many apples for us to eat so some of them ended up spoiling."

Comment: You can drop both and just keep "... bought too many ...". If you *have* to choose between *little* and *few*, pick *few* in this case.

Comment: Only "a few" is possible. It means that you bought a small number of apples more than you needed to.

Comment: *A few* is for countable things (like apples); *little* would go with *too much* for non-countable things, like *a little too much flour*.

Comment: Why wouldn't you upvote the answer?

Answer (score 1):

As [@stangdon](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122190/a-little-too-many-or-a-few-too-many#comment246209_122190) comments, *a **few** is for countable things (like apples); **little** would go with **too much** for non-countable things, like **a little too much flour.*** Here it is in pictures ([link1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20few%20too%20many%2Ca%20few%20too%20much&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20too%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20too%20much%3B%2Cc0), [link2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20little%20too%20many%2Ca%20little%20too%20much&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20little%20too%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20little%20too%20much%3B%2Cc0))...

[image]

[image]